# Microsoft MVC Template - Full Trust Microsoft.Owin - alternatives

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ok so I understand that Microsoft has decided not to support anything less than Full Trust when it comes to the standard template they now provide for MVC applications.

This is a bummer as I bought a shared windows account on HostGator and they don't allow nor will allow Full Trust on their shared windows accounts.

My question is are there alternatives to the Microsoft.Owin (which I think controls the account management stuff) so that I can publish my site to my shared account?

**Ultimately I switched to a host that allows Full Trust.**

Comment: Consider switching to a better host.

Comment: @SLaks do you have a suggestion on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just OWIN.  The System.Web.Mvc.dll binary itself requires full trust for some of its code paths.  Your only option is to take your business elsewhere, unfortunately.  The ASP.NET team has officially obsoleted Medium Trust and no longer supports it, which means that Medium Trust-only hosters are rapidly going to be left in the lurch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was able to find another host.  When did they make this decision?

Comment: Around 18 months ago.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698981 for more information.  Since ASP.NET's implementation of partial trust doesn't guarantee isolation, there's no point for its continued existence, so we're killing it.